# What approach for showing custom user fields on a node?

Tags: 7, entities, users

I've added a few custom user fields which users complete when registering.

What is the simplest approach to show these fields when viewing content that user has created?

For example, when viewing a blog entry I can see the 'submitted by..' and their name. I would like to use my custom user fields to expand that summary.

I've got no problem using views, or creating/modifying the theme etc, but I'd like some guidance on the easiest approach before I start out. (It's too easy to hack away on one approach in Drupal when there's a much easier solution!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this with two steps.

1. Create a theme function that will take the user object and render what you want to render instead of submitted by username.
2. Alter the node template or use the preprocess_node and get the user from the node $node->uid and use hour theme function to replace the default submitted by with your custom value.

Doing it like this should be quick, easy and simple.

Comment: This sounds like a very good blend of simplicity and flexibility and it's an approach I wouldn't have considered.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I'm only using drupal 6 but I think these answers can lead you to a solution:

1. With the core profile module there is a block "Author information"
2. You can use the [Author Pane](http://drupal.org/project/author_pane) module but it doesn't have a stable release for D7 yet.
3. You can use views to build an author block:

If you're using profile from core:

> Create a user view
>   Set the argument to User: uid
>   Choose "Provides default argument" set to "User ID from URL" and check "Also look for a node and use the node author"
>   Add your user profile fields.

If you use [Content Profile](http://drupal.org/project/content_profile)

> Create a node view
>   Set the argument to Node: Nid
>   Choose "Provides default argument" set to "Node ID from URL"
>   Create a relationships to retrieve the content profile
>   Add your content profile fields.

Comment: Looks like Profile2 has replaced Content Profile in D7, but it looks interesting! The issue I'm having when using views is getting the fields to appear in a single node view, but that's for a separate question :-) I'll give the Profile2 module a go..