# Display author profile fields in nodes created by that user

Tags: entities, users

I have a user profile with extra fields like company address and company name etc.

I also have a content type *job* where i'd like to use the author's profile info (company name, address) in the content created by that author.

How do I use fields from the author profile in my nodes created via the *job* content type?

Is there something like a *token field* that I can use in my content type to display profile fields?

I know in views there's an option to use relationships, but I'd like to not use views for this if possible.

Comment: If you do not want to use Views, you can use custom theming function and templates as proposed here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4683/what-approach-for-showing-custom-user-fields-on-a-node.

Answer (score 0):

1)Go to **admin/config/accountsetting** then manage field **add fields (company name, address  and company name)** into it.

2)Go to your content type **job** add fields **(company name, address  and company name)** as a existing field not as a new field.find your existing field from the list of available dropdown and select it and save.

Comment: I don't see how the node fields would be prefilled with the user profile data of the author upon node creation.